# forEach is not working but map is

Tags: javascript, arrays

An extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50832132/data-returned-by-youtube-api-seems-immutable/50832207#50832207), the solution by @CertainPerformance is working fine.

```
const query = qs.stringify({ ...API_QUERY_PARAMS, q: this.state.searchString });
const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?${query}`

const { data } = await axios.get(url);

await Promise.all(data.items.map(async (vid) => {
  let id = vid.id.videoId; //Individual video ID
  const individualQuery = qs.stringify({ ...INDIVIDUAL_API_QUERY_PARAMS, id      });
  const individualURL = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?${individualQuery}`;
  const { data } = await axios.get(individualURL);
  vid.statistics = data.items[0].statistics
}))

this.setState({ videos: data.items });
```

I was thinking it could be use `forEach` instead of `map`. However if I swap to `forEach` it will do nothing and `state.videos` will return nothing.

Checking from this [article](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f), specifically this statement

> Well, the forEach() method doesn’t actually return anything (undefined). It simply calls a provided function on each element in your array. This callback is allowed to mutate the calling array.

And hence forEach theoretically should work too but why it's not the case? For example, the `forEach` should behave like below which able to mutate the calling array

```js
let items = [
  {id: '123', title: 'John'},
  {id: '123', title:'sammy'}
]

items.forEach(x=> {
 x['statistics'] = { propA: 'A', propB: 'B'};
})

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Because you need to return the promises to `Promise.all`. Otherwise you're just returning `undefined`.

Comment: Did you ever look at what map() will return instead of *forEach()*??

Comment: @Robert: Yes I thought I know how map works but perhaps in this context I don't really know how `Promise.all` works instead

Comment: Do not mutate `vid` in the function

Comment: Using `Promise.all`, you will wait for all the promises to be resolved before doing anything else, otherwise you make the asynchronous code synchronous. Just `setState` for each vid you fetch `setState(state => ({ ...state, videos: [...state.videos, data] }))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `map` because `Promise.all` requires an argument of an *array*, generally with all or some of those elements in the array as `Promise`s. As you see, `forEach` does not return an array. In fact, it won't run at all once it reaches that point, an error will be thrown:

```
Promise.all(undefined).then(() => console.log('ok'))
```

> (index):30 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
>       at Function.all ()
>       at window.onload ((index):30)

You might be missing that `async` functions automatically return `Promises` that resolve once the end of their (visual) block is reached. Translating the `async` function into a standard function does exactly the same thing and explicitly returns a `Promise`, the code would look like this:

```
await Promise.all(data.items.map((vid) => {
  const id = vid.id.videoId;
  const individualQuery = qs.stringify({ ...INDIVIDUAL_API_QUERY_PARAMS, id      });
  const individualURL = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?${individualQuery}`;
  return axios.get(individualURL)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      vid.statistics = data.items[0].statistics
    });
}))
```

You have to `return` the created Promise so that `Promise.all` knows that it need to wait for all `Promise`s in the array to resolve first - this was somewhat masked behind the `async` function of the original code.